# Cognos Report not returning the total of a calculation in the report

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-11

Cognos Report,  I am trying to calculate Total Unbilled amount (7685.81) from OOP (-3235.11) using [Total Unbilled Amount] - abs ([OOP])  to get a Fees total of $4450.70.

Cognos Report,  I am running some numbers which all come in fine,  But am trying to add a Fees columns,  which just subtracts the Total Unbilled amount (7685.81) from OOP (-3235.11) using [Total Unbilled Amount] - abs ([OOP])  to get a Fees total of $4450.70.   My issue is the population of the fees in the report,  It just shows blank..  Ive tried altering the aggreagation, totaling differently etc. I simply cannot get a number to show in that field!!!

[image]

Comment: I'm uncertain what you are trying to describe, partly because the screen capture does not match your description.  Are you saying that $0 - $7,685.81 = 7,685.81 is correct, but (-3,235.11) - $0 should result in $4,450.71, not NULL (and not -$3,235.11?)

Comment: My apologies im a SQL guy and they're throwing me into the Cognos fire without any training so my description isn't the best.  But yes,  the fees I am looking to get is $4450.71,  the total unbilled is not carrying thru to the summary to be subtracted from?  Im really sorry im being vague im trying my best to learn!

Comment: So, `0 - 3235.11 = 4450.71`?

Comment: no,  im trying to get the total unbilled from the detail in the top to carry thru to the bottom summary to be subtracted from

Comment: So, how would you do that in SQL?

Comment: well in the Data Item I tried:  case when [Total Unbilled Amount] is null then Detail.[Total Unbilled (Advanced) Amount] else 0 end

Comment: I mean how would you subtract a value in one row from a value in a different row.  Are you sure you posted the correct screen capture?

Comment: thats just it,  the value in the Unbilled should be $7685.81 like it is up top,  but its coming in blank in the summary.

Comment: Blank?  Do you mean $0.00?  $0.00 <> blank.  Or did you forget to post the "summary" row.

Comment: Yes correct,  I mean that its coming in as $0.00 in the summary below,  the 3,  $0 values at the bottom left should all be $7685.81